# Vagrant / Ubuntu - How can I make environmental variables for postgresql

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, vagrant, yaml

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS.  When I set up postgres on this box, I thought I entered my username / password in either .bashrc or .profile.  I've checked both though and see nothing related to postgres.  I also looked at pg_hba.conf but nothing in the way of password / username either.  I have no problem accessing pgsql or creating databases and have the username and password.

However,  I've been hard coding in the username / password into the development apps.  I want to stop that now, so while I have a yaml file with

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: development
  username: <%= ENV['PG_USER'] %>
  passowrd: <%= ENV['PG_PASS'] %>
  host: localhost
```

I'm not sure how to write the variables and where to store them. I did some searching on this before asking, and some of the info was a bit confusing and more importantly, varied.

Side note - I know database.yaml may not be the best or only option, for now it's the one I'm staying with though.

Answer (score 0):

Storing usernames and passwords into environment variables is unsafe since environment is meant to be accessible and is shared between running programs. Simply store the username and password into yaml file. You can crypt the values if there is a change of non-admin persons to see them.